# Can I get an example that check 'Endorsement Policy' in node.js application?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I read below statement from 'Transaction Flow' chapter of hyperledger-fabric docs.
( https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/txflow.html )

*If the client application intends to submit the transaction to Ordering Service to update the ledger, the application determines if the specified **endorsement policy** has been fulfilled before submitting*

Does the 'Endorsement Policy' means endorsement policy for chaincode that can be specified in the CLI?
 ( c.f.  -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')" )

If so, can I get an example that check 'Endorsement Policy' in node.js application?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check for consistency of endorsements is already part of the SDK, so it should be transparent for the client code, please take a look on [Channel.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js#L1445):

```
        var endorsements = [];
        let proposalResponse = proposalResponses;
        if(Array.isArray(proposalResponses)) {
            for(let i=0; i<proposalResponses.length; i++) {
                // make sure only take the valid responses to set on the consolidated response object
                // to use in the transaction object
                if (proposalResponses[i].response && proposalResponses[i].response.status === 200) {
                    proposalResponse = proposalResponses[i];
                    endorsements.push(proposalResponse.endorsement);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (proposalResponse && proposalResponse.response && proposalResponse.response.status === 200) {
                endorsements.push(proposalResponse.endorsement);
            }
        }

        if(endorsements.length < 1) {
            logger.error('sendTransaction - no valid endorsements found');
            return Promise.reject(new Error('no valid endorsements found'));
}
```

Now this code checks that it got consistent endorsement response from all endorsement peers request has been sent to.

While it's up to the client application logic to ensure whenever it has satisfiable set of endorsement signatures. E.g. if endorsement policy is

```
AND(OR(Org1.member, Org3.member), OR(Org2.member, Org3.member))
```

and you got signatures only of org1 and org2, the above check will pass, while application has to be aware of endorsement rule and understand that responses of org1 and org2 alone is not enough and need to get also endorsement from org3.

With upcoming versions of Fabric, most likely v1.2 there will be service discovery capabilities where application will be provide capabilities to automatically detect satisfiable subsets of endorsing peers, making this part easier for app developer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. :)
Do you know where can I find the example of client application logic that checks endorsement policy, you mentioned above.

Comment: No, but this is fairly simple right now, as endorsement policy statically configured within client app, e.g. client logic is aware of endorsing policy hence already sends endorsement request to involved peers.